# Eclipse Tycho change default source location

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I am trying to build eclipse plugin using Tycho, eventhough we are using maven, our project structure is bit different than standard tycho/maven structure. (because due to company standards)

Project structure is as shown below:

```
com.test.plugin
|
------ build
-------|
-------------plugin-artifacts
-------------|classes  //compiled classes
-------------|META-INF

//here folder structure is bit different, pom.xml inside build directory
will take care of generating plugin-artifacts.
```

So my question is , is it possible to specify tycho to take `build/plugin-artifacts` as root directory to generate plugin jar file, instead of taking `com.test.plugin` as root?

I am following [Lars Vogel's](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTycho/article.html) tutorial to learn tycho plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tycho doesn't allow to configure where the OSGi manifest is located. It always has to be at `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` relative to the `pom.xml` file.

Most other input and output folders are configurable though, so you could simply put the `pom.xml` at `com.test.plugin/build/plugin-artifacts`, and configure the paths in the `build.properties` (located in the same folder as the `pom.xml`) and POM.

Comment: Is it not possible to configure such a way that tycho builds plugin from `\foo\bar` folder than `\foo` ?

Comment: As I already said, the only option is to move the pom.xml file.

Comment: This should be configurable especially since the required locations don't conform with the standard maven layouts...